# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Project migration from 6.0.0.1 to 6.1.0.0 fails

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I've updated my Worklight Studio to v6.1.0.0.
When i try to open my project, it fails with this error message:

```
[2013-12-16 10:29:56] FWLPL0019E: Migrating the project from version 6.0.0 to version 6.1.0.0 has failed because this migration path is not supported: Failed reading application-descriptor.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of my apps in that project were missing the "application-descriptor.xml" file for unknown reason...
I've deleted the folders for those apps, then the migration succeeded.