# Worklight Development server not starting up

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, java-server, worklight-server

I am currently working with IBM Worklight and came up with this trouble. Everything worked perfectly and suddenly I was updating my Android ADT and then out of nowhere, my worklight server got turned off and It doesn't start up. I searched through the site and could not come up with questions addressing the exact problem.

When I click on the start server, I get the following log info.

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.7.0_51-b13 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0010I: The server worklight is shutting down because of a previous initialization error.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0036I: The server worklight stopped after 8.827 seconds.
```

And a popup box which says

```
Server Worklight Development Server failed to start.
```

Here is what my screen looks like..
[image: Screenshot of my workbench]

Kindly help me guys

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in the Worklight Development Server console view? What do you see in the Problems view?

Comment: @IdanAdar I have mentioned the text in my console view already in the question. As far as the problems view, there is nothing in there. It is clear of errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. From the Servers view, delete "Worklight Development Server"
2. Restart Eclipse
3. The development server should be automatically re-generated

See if starting it now works.

---

Per the comments:

Without having the original project to recreate the (new) migration issue, my only solution is to create a new project and copy the web resources to it.

Comment: I did as you said.. it is automatically re-generated but the same problem still exists.. the same message appears at the console view

Comment: Then I suggest to use a new instance of Eclipse, install ADT and Worklight Studio and see if the problem persists.

Comment: the server started running but now I am getting a new error. The worklight version which I worked with was older and since this is newer version, It throws up the error `[2014-03-22 19:37:45] FWLPL0019E: Migrating the TGMC project from version 6.1.0.0 to version 6.1.0.1 has failed because there is no available migration path. 
Use the latest Worklight Studio or the latest "IBM Worklight Studio Upgrader" from IBM Fix Central site http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/ `

Comment: Well, follow the instructions?

Comment: Yes I did follow the instructions.. i saw a question here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607539/ibm-worklight-6-1-project-migration-from-6-0-0-1-to-6-1-0-0-fails
but it doesn't help. My project has application-descriptor.xml file in the app folder

Comment: Follow what? Did you use the "latest "IBM Worklight Studio Upgrader" from IBM Fix Central"?

Comment: I couldn't find the latest "IBM Worklight Studio Upgrader" from that website. 0 results were found

Comment: Well, I don't know... my suggestion for you is to either upload the project (a version of it before youv'e tried to upgrade it) so I could try it myself, of if you are an IBM customer you may also choose to open a PMR.

Comment: There is some backup file generated. I will upload it and let you know. May I know where to send you? I am not an IBM customer and I am using developer edition

Comment: You can upload to dropbox.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69207680/TGMC_2014_03_22_193637.backup.zip

Here is the link

Comment: This backup .zip is missing project files so I am unable to import it. Upload a version of the project prior to ugprading. Or you can just create a new Worklight project and copy your html/js/css into it

Comment: I created a new project and copied the `common` folder. Now everything works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I got similar errors that the upgrade from 6.1.0.0 to 6.1.0.1 failed after updating from eclipse.  I deleted the project, recreated it, copied the common folder into it, recreated the environments (android and iphone).  Then I was getting errors on both the iphone and andriod build about wlBuildResources/.../obscureArgs.txt not found.  I deleted wlBuildResources and started eclipse with -clean.  That seems to have at least gotten the project to build.  Idan if you want to try this project upgrade/migration you can get it from:  https://github.com/attdevsupport/ATT_APIPlatform_Worklight/tree/master/ATT_WL_InAppMessaging

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

Under your root folder of the worklight project there would be a hidden file under ***.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs***

Open the same with TextEdit or NotePad. Delete the line ***wl_version=6.1.0.0.......*** and save the file. Now try to open the project again it would get recreated with the latest version number.